# How to change the frame of textview as content changes?

Tags: ios, uitextview

Is it possible to change both width and height of the textview with respect to content. Here, the height of the text only varies when user enters an new line character.

How to do pinch zoom on textview, such that font doesn't look blur. It needs to be work on from iOS5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it has worked for me. viewNote is my textView object. it is for height

```
CGRect frame = viewNote.frame;
NSLog(@"Text Size height : %f",frame.size.height);

CGSize textViewSize;
if (isIPhone) {
    textViewSize = [viewNote.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]
                                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(309, 10000)
                                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
}else{
    textViewSize = [viewNote.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:30]
                                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(768, 10000)
                                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
}

frame.size.height = textViewSize.height;
viewNote.frame = frame;
NSLog(@"Text Size height : %f",frame.size.height);
```

Comment: It is easier to change to alone height or width of textview. But, I would like to change both width and height dynamically. It doesn't work for me

Comment: @ karthik, mohitpopat is posted some code. Based on that you have to understand and try it. If not possible then come back again, but do not expect complete answer here.

Comment: While trying the above for width frame changes inappropriately and blinks while changing the frame of textview

Comment: calculate the frame as per your requirements. you have to make that calculations.